# How to test the significance of an intervention

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation

I have a database of hourly energy consumption of a country throughout the year. I wish to test if an energy efficiency measure (daylight saving)which is instated twice a year and removed twice a year has: H0: negative or no improvement //H1: improved efficiency

The daily profile shows two peaks, one occurring at noon and the second peak at 10 pm. Furthermore, I wish to see if, throughout the year, temperature variations affect the energy use or the energy efficient measures themselves.

I have organized the data in groups of weeks, to reduce variations due to weekends and public holidays. It shows the 4 weeks prior to the hour change and the four weeks after.
[image]

I'm at a loss as to what statistical method will be most appropriate for this analysis.

Thanks in advance for any help or pointers.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that it will be inherently hard to detect such effect, should there be one. The switch to and from daylight savings time always occurs at almost fixed points in time (slightly different, so that they concide with a weekend night). Thus, their effect can hardly be discerned from the seasonal effect: after a switch to DST, you may observe less consumption of energy which may be due to longer daylight hours as well as to the effect of the switch itself.

I think you would need a sample with some communities which adhere to DST and communities otherwise similar in all respects which do not, and compare their consumptions. Failing that, you might consider very short periods of time before and after the DST switch as "seasonally equivalent" and perform a standard intervention analysis: but there will be much noise (because even in two consecutive weeks weather can be entirely different, and this heavily influences consumption of energy).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try the standard intervention analysis. But I do concur with your point on needing a control sample to test against. Unfortunately, I won't be able to have access to such data.